# Declare array of integers and floats in f77

Tags: arrays, fortran77

Quick question:

Is it possible to declare one array with integers and floats in Fortran 77? If yes, how?

Thanks

MW

Answer (score 1):

**One** array with **both** integers and floats (reals) inside? No. It has to have a singular type.